# Message: You have requested a non-existent service "http"

Tags: symfony, render, twig

I have a problem with render tag in twig.

I got a message: `"You have requested a non-existent service "http"`. When i use `{% render url("render_menu") %}`

`render_menu` route works fine

help me !

P/S: Sorry about my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a correct way, but with an old version. You should upgrade to fix security issues AND resolve your problem.

A security issue changed the way to use `render`: http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-symfony-2-0-20-and-2-1-5-released

Documentation has been updated:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html#using-edge-side-includes

Answer (score 1):

You are using `render` tag wrong. If you want to render action, that is behind your `render_menu` - you should pass it in format `YourBundle:YourController:YourAction`.

For example, if you have `menuAction()` that is behind route `render_menu`, then in Twig you should call it like this:

```
{% render "YourBundle:YourController:menu" %}
```

Note, that you have to strip out `Action` word when calling `menuAction` in `render` tag.

Comment: This notation is no longer available for `render`: http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-symfony-2-0-20-and-2-1-5-released